# Less redundant way of if else statements

Tags: python

I have the code:

```
bytedata = decompressed_data

guid, sha1_hash = (
    x.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="big")
    for x in get_resource_descriptor(head_revision)
)

for i in list(zip(resource_references, replace_with)):
    replace, replace_with = i[0], i[1]

    if replace.startswith("g"):
        if use_compressed_integers(compression_flags):
            replace = guid + varint.encode(int(replace[1:]))
        else:
            replace = guid + struct.pack(">I", int(replace[1:]))

    elif replace.startswith("h"):
        replace = sha1_hash + int(replace[1:]).to_bytes(length=20, byteorder="big")

    if replace_with.startswith("g"):
        replace_with = struct.pack(">I", replace_with[1:])

    elif replace_with.startswith("h"):
        replace_with = sha1_hash + int(replace_with[1:]).to_bytes(
            length=20, byteorder="big"
        )

    bytedata = bytedata.replace(replace, replace_with)

return bytedata
```

Is there a less redundant way of writing the same code? There's so many if else statements, and it looks ugly and redundant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand what you find redundant about the code. Does it not actually have to check whether the strings start that way, and do something different in each case? Anyway, questions about code elegance are off topic here; consider [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3):

The new Python 3.10 Structural Pattern Matching (released in [PEP 636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/)) introduces the `match/case` statements and handles the excess of if/elif nicely.

Your `for` statement will look like that:

```
for i in list(zip(resource_references, replace_with)):
        replace, replace_with = i[0], i[1]

        match replace[0]:
            case "g":
                if use_compressed_integers(compression_flags):
                    replace = guid + varint.encode(int(replace[1:]))
                else:
                    replace = guid + struct.pack(">I", int(replace[1:]))

            case "h":
                replace = sha1_hash + int(replace[1:]).to_bytes(length=20, byteorder="big")

        match replace_with[0]:
            case "g":
                replace_with = struct.pack(">I", replace_with[1:])

            case "h":
                replace_with = sha1_hash + int(replace_with[1:]).to_bytes(
                length=20, byteorder="big"
            )

        bytedata = bytedata.replace(replace, replace_with)
```

Answer (score 1):

since Python (before 3.10) lacks as`switch/case` statement, i find myself often using dictionaries that map my input data to functions.

like so:

```py
fun2 = {
 'g': lambda x: struct.pack(">I", x),
 'h': sha1_hash + int(x).to_bytes(length=20, byteorder="big"),
}
# ...
replace_with = fun2[replace[0]](replace_with[1:])
```

or, if you don't like lambdas and prefer local functions instead:

```py
bytedata = decompressed_data

guid, sha1_hash = (
    x.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="big")
    for x in get_resource_descriptor(head_revision)
)

def handle_g(x, compressed=False, prefix=b''):
  if compressed:
    return prefix + varint.encode(int(x[1:]))
  else:
    return prefix + struct.pack(">I", int(x[1:]))
def handle_h(x, compressed=False, prefix=b''):
  return sha1_hash + int(x[1:]).to_bytes(length=20, byteorder="big")
def handle_default(x, compressed=False, prefix=b''):
  return x
handles = {
 'g': handle_g,
 'h': handle_h,
}

do_compress = use_compressed_integers(compression_flags)


for i in zip(resource_references, replace_with):
    replace, replace_with = i[0], i[1]

    replace = handles.get(replace[0], handle_default)(replace, do_compress, guid)
    replace_with = handles.get(replace_with[0], handle_default)(replace_with)

    bytedata = bytedata.replace(replace, replace_with)
```

sidenote: there is typically no use for using `for _ in list(zip(...))`: the `list()` will just add overhead (as the iterable has to be expanded to a full list first) for no obvious gain. much better to just use `for _ in zip(...)`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thanks, i've updated the answer accordingly